# PHP почему не работает if?

Tags: php

Есть форма которая сохраняет настройки в виде массива, массив вида:

```
Array
(
    [p1] => 4560
    [p2] => 4567
    [proxy2] => 
    [proxy1] => 0
)
```

или

```
Array
(
    [p1] => 4560
    [p2] => 4567
    [proxy1] => on
    [proxy2] => 185.80.128.172:3128
)
```

сама форма

```
<form action="" method= "POST"> 
На сайте 4566 страниц. 
 <p>Парсить с : </p><p> <input type= "text" name= "p1" value="4560"> </p> 
 <p>по: </p><p> <input type= "text" name= "p2"  value="4567"></p>
<p>Использовать прокси : </p><p> <input type="checkbox" name= "proxy1" checked="checked"> </p> <p>Список прокси с новой строки: </p>

<p><textarea name= "proxy2">185.80.128.172:3128</textarea></p>
 <input type= "submit" value= "Отправить"> 
 </form>
```

в пхп обработчике делаю следуйщее

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($configs);
echo "</pre>";


if ($configs['proxy1']=='0') {
    echo '<p>Парсим без прокси : </p><br>'; 
    $data=get_url($url);
}

if ($configs['proxy1']=='on') {
    echo '<p>Используем прокси : </p>'.$prox1.'<br>'; 
    $data=get_url_pr($url, $prox1); 
}
```

в результате, если $configs['proxy1']=='on' то все работает нормально, а если [proxy1] => 0 то выполняются два IF, тоесть выполняется код

```
    echo '<p>Парсим без прокси : </p><br>'; 
    $data=get_url($url);

    echo '<p>Используем прокси : </p>'.$prox1.'<br>'; 
    $data=get_url_pr($url, $prox1);
```

условие не срабатывает, почему так?

пробовал так, тоже при начение 0, выполняется условие будто в настройках on

```
if ($configs['proxy1']=='on') {
        echo '<p>Используем прокси : </p>'.$prox1.'<br>'; 
        $data=get_url_pr($url, $prox1); 
    }else{
        echo '<p>Парсим без прокси : </p><br>'; 
        $data=get_url($url);
}
```

пример выполнения скрипта http://copy-lend.ru/work/pars-marathons/index.php

**UP:** Решение, может кому пригодится

```
if ($configs['proxy1']!=true) {
    echo '<p>Парсим без прокси : </p><br>'; 
    $data=get_url($url);
}

if ($configs['proxy1']!=false) {
    echo '<p>Используем прокси : </p>'.$prox1.'<br>'; 
    $data=get_url_pr($url, $prox1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `0` и `on` использовать `true` и `false`.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `0 == on` [равно **true**](http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php).

Используйте либо строгое сравнение `===`, либо используйте else, а не второй иф, либо просто используйте само значение, оно будет автоматически приведено к булеву типу:

```
if (!$configs['proxy1']) // сработает для 0
if ($configs['proxy1']) // сработает для on
```